# React Native app is not running from react-native run-android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I have just installed the react-native as explained into documentation. And created new app called "testApp".

The app not running by `npx react-native run-android`. I searched so much across internet but couldn't find any solution which help me out.

Then I tried to install app from android studio it installed successfully then I started pm server and it was working. But what is the problem in `npx react-native run-android` command I can't understand it.

Here is screenshot of error:
[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: Do you have an Emulator or real device connected?

Comment: Yes I have connected Real device

Comment: Do you see you device in the output of adb devices ? and did you open developer setting in you device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below command

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

Comment: Ooh You are a Genius...!! And I'm a Fool, I didn't tried that...!! Thanks a lot it worked...)

Comment: Nope, you are not fool, it is an minor mistake. If it is worked then accept my answer